# Search if not contains in SOLR?

Tags: solr

I have a Some String in SOLR *`"Starting User"`*,*`"Ending User"`*,*`"Friend"`*
etc... I want to see the results no having user

I tried *`-t1:*User*`* but it is not bringing appropriate result.

Comment: with *User* ...are you looking for wildcard search ?

Comment: Anhijit Bashetti this is not working and yes I am looking for a wild card search

Comment: whats the fieldType used for the field t1?

Comment: String and it's copied

Comment: so whats the exact text that you index n the text you are trying to search?

Comment: Strating User is the string and then I am trying to removed the document which are having keyword User

Comment: for this you are using String fieldType, because of the string field type its not been tokenized...change the field type for that field....make the fieldType as text_general and try...

Comment: What result do you get? You usually have to start with something to subtract something, so `*:* -field:Value` might give a better result.

Comment: use edismax: defType=edismax
then set parameter where you want to search: qf=title+title_edge+title_ngram
then set q: q=-"search string"
If you have all tokenizers configured propertly, this works (just checked :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If t1 is defined as type **string**, and you indexed the data "You are good boy", and you search with good/boy - you will not get any results. You have to use complete phrase

Solution is, use "**text_general**" for t1. So then when you index above phrase, it will be tokenized as you, are, good,boy etc and will return results when you search with good/boy

Please try to understand how analyzers, tokenizer and filters work during indexing and searching. happy Learning

Comment: Thanks Ramzy but the search is working on lowercase and in some cases i have strings like "Starting.Serivce2","WAITING.FOR-MSDN" in this case it not at proper as you I have changed the type to text_general but the above meintion is not working

Comment: You can also create your own fieldtype. For example, you can create a fieldType which is the same as `text_general` except that you can add a filter `lowerCaseFactory` ! You can find some help [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Type+Definitions+and+Properties) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers).